# Android sqlite if rowid exsist update else insert

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, insert-update

I have to give a user rating to android application through my android applicatiion ,Once i give the rating it will be stored in sqlite database ,again i give the rating for same application it will stored once again in database ,i want if row id of the application already exists it will update the table else insert the values to the table ,i know its very simple but its trouble to me ,thanks for your help...
   My code :
    Rating bar setOnRatingBarChangeListener:

```
   ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                    boolean fromUser) {
            txtRatingValue.setText(String.valueOf(rating * 20) + "Rating");
            Log.d("Raating ", String.valueOf(rating));
            strA[21] = String.valueOf(rating);
            String userRating=String.valueOf(rating);
            curRate=Float.parseFloat(userRating);
           DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(Activity1.this);
            db.insertuserrate(strA, cxt);

        }
    });
   public  void insertuserrate(String Str[],Context cxt) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor c = null;
    String strId="";
    ArrayList<String> userRatepoit= new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     {
            values.put(KEY_RID, Str[0]);
            values.put(ALL_name, Str[1]);
            values.put(ALL_isbn, Str[2]);
            etc...
            values.put(ALL_book_rating, Str[20]);
            values.put(ALL_book_userrating, Str[21]);
         db.insert(TABLE_USERRATE, null, values);
         Log.d("inserted success", TABLE_USERRATE);
            // Closing database connection
        }
try {

db.close();
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Here you are only inserting, where is the code for update?

Comment: sure,i try a lot but not working for me (update) you just give sample code for insert else update@NigamPatro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if rowid exists by running a select query similar to the one below:

```
public boolean rowIdExists(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select 1 from " + TABLE_USERRATE
            + " where row_id=?", new String[] { "" + id });
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return exists;
}
```

Then use it in your current implementation to determine whether to insert or to update:

```
if (rowIdExists(someID)) {
    db.updateuserrate(strA, cxt);
} else {
    db.insertuserrate(strA, cxt);
}
```

Comment: its working fine but all the row values are updated by same value i want to update particular row only @bwegs

Comment: @murugananthamselvam what does your `update` query look like? Please post it in your question.

Comment: your code is working fine i just mistake my update query tanq for your help.@bwegs

Comment: if my question is correct please upvote my question,and save me ASK Question block tanq @bwegs

Answer (score 0):

Just try to update the row. If it wasn't found, insert:

```java
void updateOrInsert(...) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cb.put(...); // all except the ID
        if (db.update(TABLE_USERRATE, cv,
                      KEY_RID + " = " + Str[0], null) == 0) {
            cv.put(KEY_RID, Str[0]);
            db.insert(TABLE_USERRATE, null, cv);
        }
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```